# StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase for char

Tags: c#, case-insensitive

How can I compare `char` using an arbitrary comparer?

I've tried using `StringComparer` but it only works if I convert the `char` to string.

```
var cmp = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
char a = 'a';
char A = 'A';
cmp.Equals(a.ToString(), A.ToString()) //true - works
cmp.Equals(a, A) //false, working on the .Equals(object,object)
```

My guess would be that there is a call to whatever StringComparer is using to compare the characters.

Comment: 1) For simple cases using `char.ToLower`/`char.ToUpper` would work. But I'm pretty sure that it won't work for some unicode code points. 2) You could convert to `string` before comparing, but that produces garbage and costs performance.

Comment: What is the problem with converting to string and using the methods you mentioned?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've updated the question and using ToUpper is not a trivial solution anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `StringComparer` class, you can see what's happening.  The `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` member creates a new instance of the `CultureAwareComparer` class:

```
private static readonly StringComparer _invariantCultureIgnoreCase = new CultureAwareComparer(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true);
```

The `CultureAwareComparer` class implements the `Equals(String, String)` method and takes the culture and case options into account. It does not implement `Equals(Object, Object)`, which is defined in the `StringComparer` base class and called instead when you're trying to compare 2 `char`s. The definition of `StringComparer.Equals(Object, Object)` is:

```
public new bool Equals(Object x, Object y) {
    if (x == y) return true;
    if (x == null || y == null) return false;
    String sa = x as String;
    if (sa != null) {
        String sb = y as String;
        if( sb != null) {
            return Equals(sa, sb);
        }
    }
    return x.Equals(y);
}
```

As you can see, it converts both `char`s to `String` and then calls the `String.Equals(String, String)` method, the standard `String` comparison that doesn't take culture or case into account. So, if you want to compare `char`s with a `StringComparer` culture, you'll have to convert them to string first.

Comment: Yes this is my conclusion too, I also looked further into the part that does the string comparison but ended up at an internal_call.